# ReactJS Can't move footer to the bottom in Sidebar with justify content space-between

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to move  to the bottom of the 
but Footer stick to the top

try to add justify-content: space-between / align-self: flex-end

and it isn't working

**What I expected**

[image]

**What I get**

[image]

Trying to inspect element in chrome, the bottom part is covered with purple indicator

here's the code

**Sidebar.js**

```
    const Sidebar = (props) => {
    return (
            <ProSidebar className='ProSidebar' >
                    <SidebarHeader className='Header'>
                        <img src={logo}></img>    
                    </SidebarHeader>
                    <div className='Line'/>
                    <SidebarContent className='Menu'>
                        <text>Content1</text>
                        <text>Content2</text>
                    </SidebarContent>
                    <div className='Line'/>
                    <SidebarFooter className='Footer'>
                        <text>Footer</text>
                    </SidebarFooter>
            </ProSidebar>
    )
}

export default Sidebar
```

**Sidebar.css**

```
.ProSidebar {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-image: url("../resource/side-bg.png");
  background-size: cover;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: larger;
  text-align: center;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.Header {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Menu {
  flex: 3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.Footer {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: auto;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to edit the CSS file, just set SidebarFooter style and you are good to go.

```
        <SidebarFooter style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 0, width: "100%" }}>
          <Item
            title="Item"
            to="/item"
            icon={<ItemOutlinedIcon />}
            selected={selected}
            setSelected={setSelected}
          />
        </SidebarFooter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Justify contents aligns items horizontally on the container.
In your case you might want to try this

```
.Header {
   align-items: flex-start;
}
.Menu {
   align-items: center;
}
.Footer {
   align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: try it, it's only move the content of the footer, but footer still stick to the top